# Java - Как сделать ссылку на переменную по названию из String

Tags: java, переменные

Моя цель понять, как использовать переменную из другого запущенного класса по `String` названию в Java.

Java 21

Comment: Переменную или поле? (в первом случае - никак, во втором через `Class.getDeclaredField("fieldname").get(...)`)

Comment: Но лучше расскажите, что вы _действительно_ хотите сделать таким необычным способом.

Comment: Я хочу сделать консоль, через которую можно будет изменять значение переменных в другой программе на java

Comment: Каких переменных?  Откуда первая программа должна узнать о каких-то _переменных_ во второй программе?

Comment: через командную строку будет вводится название переменной из другой программы, пробел и её значение и это все будет присваиваться

Comment: а та, другая программа - тоже ваша? в том смысле, что вы можете править ее исходный код и пересобирать?

Comment: То есть первая программа по сути выступает как отладчик второй программы и должна иметь возможность менять значения внутри этой второй программы?

Comment: да, первая программа выступает как отладчик второй программы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае переменной это невозможно. Но если это поле, то как написал Nofate, это можно сделать используя `Class.getDeclaredField("fieldname").get(...))`.